# Creating a has_one association with an object which doesn't belong to anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'll admit it right off, I'm new to Rails, but not to programming in general or anything.

I followed [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and have a decent understanding of how things work in his safe and controlled space, but now that I'm out in the real world I'm having some problems.

The little project I'm working on to learn this stuff is a very simple rails app where a user can add a song to the database and mark it as their "favorite" track. While songs are uploaded by a user, they are not owned by a user, because any other user can pick a previously uploaded song to mark as their "favorite" as well.

So what makes sense to me is for the user model to have

```
has_one :song
validates :song_id, presence: true
```

And for the song model to have no association rules, because a song doesn't "belong" to a user, it belongs to the entire app for any user to choose as their favorite.

However when I try this in the rails console, and attempt to do user.song an error is thrown:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: songs.user_id: 

SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs"  WHERE "songs"."user_id" =
?  ORDER BY "songs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

I can see what it is trying to do, it's interpreting what I say as meaning the songs model has a user_id column to join the users table, but what I want is the opposite. I read the documentation and found that the `belongs_to` association does the opposite, so I threw that in for the user model instead like this:

```
belongs_to :song
validates :song_id, presence: true
```

And this actually works! But... it doesn't make any sense. The user shouldn't belong to anyone, it should have a favorite song. Furthermore, it also doesn't make sense to say the song object `has_many` users, because users, like songs, aren't really "owned" by anyone, the way a tweet would be owned by a user, lets say.

I mean, if this is the way to do it (making users belong to songs, and having songs have many users) I'm ok with that, it just doesn't really make sense to me, and since I'm new to Rails I figured there's probably a better way of doing this which makes more sense in the code of the models.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this is the Rails way to do it.

The :belongs_to and :has_one predicates are both 1-1 relations, and the distinction is mostly just indications as to on which object the primary key reference resides to link the two objects. The natural choice of which to use often falls out of whether the relation might actually be more like 1-to-many or many-to-1.

:belongs_to means the key reference is local. This is often used when using composition; say if you had shelves in a cabinet, each shelf 'belongs to' a cabinet, and the cabinet would 'has_many' the shelf object. The key is on the shelf, because that is the object of which there are many.

:has_one means the key reference is on the opposing object. It is often used if it might just as well :has_many the opposing object.

In your case, you imagine describing the relationship as the song :has_many admirers, each of which :belongs_to the song (as an admirer, via the 'favorite' relation).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html gives a much better overview with many examples, including many-many relations.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess I was getting caught up with the whole "ownership" thing, because I didn't want users to be like "subservient" to songs or whatever, but I guess when you look at it like an admirers type object like you described (which happen to be users) that makes more sense. Thanks for the help!